# How to Change the chef environment of client

Tags: chef-infra

I have a server(infosec11) using a chef environment opsstack1.0 with old cookbooks , planned to update to new version of cookbooks.

```
Old environment name: opsstack1.0
New environment name: opsstack2.0
```

I have created new environment, but need to know how to change the chef environment of server(infosec11) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command to move the node to the new environment:

```
knife node environment set infosec11 opsstack2.0
```